# Date validator/format

Tags: c#, regex, validation, date, datetime

I am trying to validate the format of date and also validate the date equal to or less than today in C# I am trying to achieve this in c# using regular expressions.

The formats I am trying to support are dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd, yyyy/mm/dd.

```
var expressions = new List<Regex>();

expressions.Add(new Regex("^\\d{4}-((0\\d)|(1[012]))-(([012]\\d)|3[01])$"));
expressions.Add(new Regex("(((0|1)[1-9]|2[1-9]|3[0-1])\\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/((19|20)\\d\\d))$"));

return expressions;
```

Can somone please tell me what i am doing wrong in my reg ex and also suggest a better way to achieve this.

Comment: A better way: DateTime.TryParse or .TryParseExact.

Comment: https://www.icewarp.com/support/online_help/203030104.htm

Comment: Be aware, `mm` specifier is for minutes and `MM` specifier is for months. Format specifiers are case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use regular expressions for this; you can call `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` with the permitted formats as an argument.  Unlike regular expressions, this approach will also ensure that the user-provided date is valid (e.g., allowing "2016-02-29" but not "2015-02-29").

```
string inputDate = "2015-01-01";
DateTime dt;

bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate,
    new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy/MM/dd" },
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out dt);

Console.WriteLine(validDate ? dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "Invalid date"); // 01/01/2015
```

Comment: Exactly. Try to parsing `DateTime` is much better way than using regex for that case.

Comment: Use DateTime.TryParse(). If you use RegEx what about the numbers of days in certain months? What about leap years and 29th of Feb?...

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. Your regular expression here

   ```
   "^\\d{4}-((0\\d)|(1[012]))-(([012]\\d)|3[01])$"
   ```

   Can only find date format with `-`, not with `/` (that is 1999-12-25 is valid but 1997/11/15 is not). If you want to change it, you should use

   ```
   "\\d{4}(-|\/)((0\\d)|(1[012]))(-|\/)(([012]\\d)|3[01])$" //^ removed, \/ added
   ```

   Which would match both 1999-12-25 and 1997/11/15 (edit: but will also match 1998/05-28!)
2. Likewise, your regular expression here

   ```
   "(((0|1)[1-9]|2[1-9]|3[0-1])\\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/((19|20)\\d\\d))$"
   ```

   Can only match 12/11/1954 but cannot match 12-11-1954. Some more, because you put (0|1)[1-9]|2[1-9], your regex cannot match 10-11-1954. Use

   ```
   "((0|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(-|\/)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(-|\/)(19|20)\\d\\d$"
   ```

instead

But seriously, unless is a must, it is a hellish task to parse (not to say to compare) `DateTime` value with Regex! You should just use `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.Parse` together with `TimeSpan` for parsing and for comparison respectively.

Comment: You RE will match `2015-12/21`. It may be better to replace the second `(-|\/)` with `\1` (in the "1." section) or `\2` (in "2.") so the RE checks that the separator is used consistently. Also, I would use `([-\/])` rather than the ` | ` style - just personal preference; similarly use `[01]` rather than `0|1`.

Comment: Actually, you are right... Will edit my answer. Yes, the whole point is this is rather hellish task.